# Bruteforce and Conquer and Divide not giving same distance answer for Closest Pair of Points

Tags: java

I created a program that generates a user inputted number of pairs of points. It then goes through a bruteforce and divide and conquer methods to find the closest pair of points. The bruteforce method works perfectly. The divide and conquer method on the other hand gives me an output but it is different than the brute force distance almost 90% of the time. I can't seem to figure out why it is like this in my code. NOTE: Some of the comments in the functions are from my teacher. Also, the `closest_pair` function along with `rec_cl_pair` have been given to me by my teacher where I must use them but had to adjust to my code (they were pseudo code for most part).

My code is:

```
import java.util.*;
import static java.lang.Math.min;

public class ClosestPair{

 private Double x;
 private Double y;

 private static Double minDist = Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;

 private static ClosestPair closestPair1 = new ClosestPair(0.0,0.0);
 private static ClosestPair closestPair2 = new ClosestPair(0.0,0.0);

 public ClosestPair(Double x, Double y){

     this.x = x;
     this.y = y;
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) {

     Double rangeMin = 0.0;
     Double rangeMax = 1000.0;

     Random r = new Random();
     Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

     System.out.print("\nEnter the number of two dimensional arrays: ");
     int dim = scan.nextInt();

     ClosestPair[] pair = new ClosestPair[dim];
     ClosestPair[] pairCopy = new ClosestPair[dim];

     for(int i = 0; i < dim; i++){

         Double xVal = rangeMin + (rangeMax - rangeMin) * r.nextDouble();
         Double yVal = rangeMin + (rangeMax - rangeMin) * r.nextDouble();

         pair[i] = new ClosestPair(xVal,yVal);
         //System.out.print(pair[i].x + ", " + pair[i].y + "\n");
     }

    /*
    for(int j = 0; j < pair.length; j++){
        System.out.print(pair[j].x + ", " + pair[j].y + "\n");
    }
    */

    pairCopy = pair;
    pair = mergeSort(pair);

    /*
    System.out.print("\n\n\n");

    for(int j = 0; j < pair.length; j++){
        System.out.print(pair[j].x + ", " + pair[j].y + "\n");
    }
    */ 

    //BRUTE FORCE PRINT STATEMENTS
    long startTime = System.nanoTime();
    bruteForce(pair);
    long endTime = System.nanoTime();
    long timeSpent = endTime - startTime;

    System.out.print("\nMin Distance = " + minDist);
    System.out.print("\n(x1,y1) = " + closestPair1.x + ", " + closestPair1.y);
    System.out.print("\n(x2,y2) = " + closestPair2.x + ", " + closestPair2.y);
    System.out.print("\nTime: " + timeSpent + "\n\n");

    minDist = 0.0;

    //CONQUER DIVIDE PRINT STATEMENTS
    startTime = System.nanoTime();
    minDist = closest_pair(pairCopy);
    endTime = System.nanoTime();
    timeSpent = endTime - startTime;

    System.out.print("Min Distance = " + minDist);
    System.out.print("\nTime: " + timeSpent);

    scan.close();
 }

 private static void bruteForce(ClosestPair[] pair) {

     for(int i = 1; i < pair.length - 1; i++){

         for(int j = i + 1; j < pair.length; j++){

             ClosestPair p = new ClosestPair(pair[i].x,pair[i].y);
             //System.out.print("\np:" + pair[i].x + ", " + pair[i].y);

             ClosestPair q = new ClosestPair(pair[j].x,pair[j].y);
             //System.out.print("\nq: " + pair[j].x + ", " + pair[j].y);

             if(getDistance(p, q) < minDist){
                    minDist = getDistance(p, q);
                    closestPair1.x = p.x;
                    closestPair1.y = p.y;
                    closestPair2.x = q.x;
                    closestPair2.y = q.y;
             }           
         }
     }
 }

 private static Double getDistance(ClosestPair p1, ClosestPair p2) {

     double xdist = p2.x - p1.x;
     double ydist = p2.y - p1.y;
     return Math.hypot(xdist, ydist);

}

 static ClosestPair[] mergeSort(ClosestPair[] a) {
     if (a.length > 1) {
         int q = a.length/2;

         ClosestPair[] leftArray = Arrays.copyOfRange(a, 0, q);
         ClosestPair[] rightArray = Arrays.copyOfRange(a,q,a.length);

         mergeSort(leftArray);
         mergeSort(rightArray);

         a = merge(a,leftArray,rightArray);
     }
    return a;
 }

 static ClosestPair[] merge(ClosestPair[] a, ClosestPair[] l, ClosestPair[] r) {

     int totElem = l.length + r.length;
     //int[] a = new int[totElem];

     int i,li,ri;

     i = li = ri = 0;

     while ( i < totElem) {
         if ((li < l.length) && (ri<r.length)) {

             if (l[li].x < r[ri].x) {
                 a[i] = l[li];
                 i++;
                 li++;
             }
             else {
                 a[i] = r[ri];
                 i++;
                 ri++;
             }
         }
         else {
             if (li >= l.length) {
                 while (ri < r.length) {
                     a[i] = r[ri];
                     i++;
                     ri++;
                 }
             }
             if (ri >= r.length) {
                 while (li < l.length) {
                     a[i] = l[li];
                     li++;
                     i++;
                 }
             }
         }
     }
     return a;

 }

 //START OF CONQUER DIVIDE SECTOIN

 static double closest_pair(ClosestPair[] p){
     int n = p.length - 1;
     p = mergeSortDC(p, 0, n); // sort all  n  points by  x-coordinate
     return rec_cl_pair(p, 0, n);
 }

 static double rec_cl_pair(ClosestPair[] p, int i, int j){ // finds closest pair between points in  p[i..j]

     // assumes input is sorted by  x-coordinate
     // at termination, input is sorted by  y-coordinate
     // i is the left index of the subarray, j is the right index

     if (j - i < 3){             // at most  3  points in  p[i..j]
         p = mergeSortDC (p, i, j);    // sort  p[i..j]  by  y-coordinate
         double delta = getDistance(p[i], p[i+1]);
         if (j - i == 1) { // two points

             minDist = delta;
             return delta;
         }
         else{

              double min1 = min(getDistance(p[i+1], p[i+2]), getDistance(p[i], p[i+2]));
              minDist = min(delta,min1);
              return minDist;
         }
     }

     int m = (i + j)/2;
     double line = p[m].x;
     double deltaL = rec_cl_pair(p, i, m);   // p[i..m]  is sorted by y-coordinate
     double deltaR = rec_cl_pair(p, m+1, j); // p[m+1..j]  is sorted by y-coordinate
     double delta = min(deltaL, deltaR);
     p = mergeDC(p, i, m, j);  // p[i..j]  is now sorted by  y-coordinate

     // Of points in p[i..j], find points in vertical strip of width 2*delta,
     // centered at line (middle of x-values), and store in array v
     int t = 0;

     ClosestPair[] v = new ClosestPair[j+1];

     for(int k = i; k < j; k++){
         if ((p[k].x > line - delta) && (p[k].x < line + delta)){
             t = t + 1;
             v[t] = p[k];
         }
     }

     // Find closest pairs among points in array  v.  NOTE: Cool math shows
     // there are at most 8 points in the strip at distance < delta. Thus,
     // in the loops below, each point is compared to at most 7 other points.
     for(int k = 1;k < t-1; k++){

         for(int s = k+1; k < min(t,k+7); s++){ // inner loop iterates <= 7 times

             delta = min(delta, getDistance(v[k],v[s]));
             minDist = delta;
             return delta;
         }
     }
     return minDist;
 }

 private static ClosestPair[] mergeSortDC(ClosestPair[] p, int low, int high) {

     // check if low is smaller then high, if not then the array is sorted
     if (low < high) {
             // Get the index of the element which is in the middle
             int middle = low + (high - low) / 2;
             // Sort the left side of the array
             mergeSortDC(p, low, middle);
             // Sort the right side of the array
             mergeSortDC(p, middle + 1, high);
             // Combine them both
             p = mergeDC(p, low, middle, high);
     }
    return p;
 }

 private static ClosestPair[] mergeDC(ClosestPair[] p, int low, int middle, int high) {

     ClosestPair[] helper = new ClosestPair[p.length];

     // Copy both parts into the helper array
     for (int i = low; i <= high; i++) {
             helper[i] = p[i];
     }

     int i = low;
     int j = middle + 1;
     int k = low;
     // Copy the smallest values from either the left or the right side back
     // to the original array
     while (i <= middle && j <= high) {
             if (helper[i].x <= helper[j].x) {
                     p[k] = helper[i];
                     i++;
             } else {
                     p[k] = helper[j];
                     j++;
             }
             k++;
     }
     // Copy the rest of the left side of the array into the target array
     while (i <= middle) {
             p[k] = helper[i];
             k++;
             i++;
     }

     return p;
 }
}
```

An example of output is:

```
Enter the number of two dimensional arrays: 50

Min Distance = 19.014027210555614
(x1,y1) = 76.99595098629398, 600.1657767818473
(x2,y2) = 87.04091889578226, 616.3098732403395
Time: 3852815

Min Distance = 29.457199999686082
Time: 414081
```

The first min distance is the bruteforce result. The second is the divide and conquer result

Comment: mergeDC in your code does not sort by y coordinate (helper[i].x <= helper[j].x)